# Quais as principais diferenças entre os formatos JSON e BSON?

Tags: json

Estive lendo um artigo na *Internet*, onde comentava-se sobre o formato `BSON`(`Json Binário`), porém fiquei com algumas dúvidas a respeito:

- O que é o `BSON`?
- Por quais motivos ele foi criado?
- Existe uma grande diferença de performance entre `JSON` x `BSON`?
- Quais linguagens o suportam?
- Quando de fato devo utilizá-lo ao invés do `JSON`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não tem como comparar a performance, **isso é muito relativo**, depende da camada e no final provavelmente ele será JSON de novo (no tempo execução), pode ser que haja um "cache" ou qualquer coisa assim, claro que na pratica como terá que primeiro ler e de-compilar, mas dependendo do software usado pode ser que nem sinta diferença. Afinal no final tanto *json* quanto *bson* terão que fazer um parse para serem usados por variáveis internas do aplicativo.

O formato no BSON seria algo como:

```
\x16\x00\x00\x00               // tamanho do documento
\x02                           // 0x02 = tipo String
hello\x00                      // nome do campo
\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00      // valor do campo
\x00                           // 0x00 = type EOO (Final do objeto)
```

Equivale a isto  `{"hello":"world"}`.

Pelo que entendi, o BSON foi criado para armazenar ou transferir JSON de forma a evitar perda de caracteres, por exemplo. Conforme o site tem [*3 objetivos*](http://bsonspec.org):

1. **Ser leve**

   Manter a sobrecarga no espaço mínimo é importante para qualquer formato de representação de dados, especialmente quando usado na rede.
2. **Transportável**

   Ele foi desenhado para ser facilmente transportável.
3. **Eficiência**

   Codificação de dados para BSON e decodificação de BSON podem ser realizadas muito rapidamente na maioria dos linguagens devido ao uso de tipos de dados C.

O BSON é usado pelo MongoDB, mas existe uma série de libs disponíveis em: http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html

Answer (score 11):

O BSON (Binary JSON) é uma extensão do JSON, e foi protagonizado inicialmente pelo MongoDB, um NoSQL Document DB, que o usa para performar o armazenamento de dados.

Ao armazenar dados no MongoDB, você já está usando o BSON.

Além de todos os dados do JSON (null, String, Number, Array, Object), o BSON suporta:

1) **MinKey, MaxKey, Timestamp** — tipos utilizados internamente no MongoDB;

2) **BinData** — array de bytes para dados binários;

3) **ObjectId** — identificador único de um registro do MongoDB;

4) **Date** — representação de data;

5) **Expressões regulares**.

Todos esse atributos a mais, tornam a manipulação de dados mais fáceis para a implementação de CRUD (create, read, update e delete) data para o MongoDB.

O BSON, como afirma a própria [BSONSpec](http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html), é usado por outras aplicações além do MongoDB.